# How can I get timestamp value in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I get timestamp value in twig as I know date formatting is possible in twig but don't know how to get timestamp value using twig function;

Comment: This is like the third time i forgot how to do this, googled it and ended up finding this answer here.
Thanks for asking such a valuable question :D

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use this

> {{ date().timestamp }}

Comment: Hm, the `date` function in Twig returned \DateTime object (PHP), and this object not have a `timestamp` property. As solution: `{{ date().format('U') }}`.

Comment: @ZhukV: There is a difference between PHP object and **Twig** object. You are correct and also wrong!! Though DateTime object doesn't have `timestamp` property, it is accessible from `Twig template`. For your information, from twig template you can access any property if there is a getter function, Like php **DateTime** object got the `getTimestamp` getter function.

Answer (score 85):

There is other solution that might be easier to understand by designers.

`{{ 'now'|date('U') }}`

(I am aware that the question is already answered and it's old)

Comment: This is the correct answer, it's the only method that will work when using Twig outside of PHP (like in a node.js environment)